# Using Vue JS $refs in function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I've set up a Vue JS method which should automatically focus on the next input field if the maxlength of a field is reached. I'm trying to pass the field to focus onto through the function but it doesn't seem to work

I've tried using various setups, it seems to work if I pass the actual ref of the field, but not through the function

Method:

```
/**
         * Switch fields
         */
        switchToField(fieldSwitchName, fieldValue, fieldLength) {
          if (String(this.fieldValue).length >= fieldLength) {
            this.$refs.fieldSwitchName.focus();
          }
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="form-row">
                    <div class="form-group col">
                      <input v-on:keyup="switchToField(AppDOBMonth, formData.AppDOBDay, 2)" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" v-model="formData.AppDOBDay" name="data[ApplicationPayday][AppDOBDay]" id="AppDOBDay" v-validate="'required|numeric|max:2|min:2|max_value:31'" type="number" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" class="form-control" placeholder="DD" @change="formData.AppDOBDay = leadingZeros(formData.AppDOBDay)">
                    </div>
                    <span class="dob-divider text-muted">/</span>
                    <div class="form-group col">
                      <input ref="AppDOBMonth" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" v-model="formData.AppDOBMonth" name="data[ApplicationPayday][AppDOBMonth]" id="AppDOBMonth" v-validate="'required|numeric|max:2|min:2|max_value:12'" type="number" maxlength="2" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric" class="form-control" placeholder="MM" @change="formData.AppDOBMonth = leadingZeros(formData.AppDOBMonth)">
                    </div>
                  </div>
```

My code should be passing the value of `fieldSwitchName` into `this.$refs.fieldSwitchName.focus();`, but it seems to be looking for a `fieldSwitchName` ref rather than the value being passed in.

What am I missing here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.` notation you're directly pointing to the name you've supplied after the `.` operator on a JS object.

To dynamically assign the accessing object key, you'll need an approach like this:

`this.$refs[fieldSwitchName].focus()`

Answer (score 0):

If **switchToField** is a variable, you need call **$ref** as array:

```
switchToField(fieldSwitchName, fieldValue, fieldLength) {
    if (String(this.fieldValue).length >= fieldLength) {
        this.$refs[fieldSwitchName].focus();
    }
}
```